# Walking animation plays but in plays for both horizontal positions and remainds standing still even in the air

Tags: debugging, game-engine, game-development

I have an action platformer game and my skeleton wont move instead the walking animation plays but it plays in both directions.I am doing a course I tried to follow along with the instructions when I first got the bug could not figure it out. I also tried to copy the code directly still the same problem.

I am at my wits end. Here is the code for my game maker studio 2 project this is the object skeleton code

```
thePlayer = collision_line(x, y, x + (image_xscale * visionLength), y, objHero, false, true)

switch(myState) {
#region Idle
case EnemyState.Idle:
    //Check for getting hit
    if(hit) {
        EnemyTakeDamage(sprSkeletonTakeHit);
    }
    //Move to Walking state
    if(alarm[0] == -1) {
        myState = EnemyState.Walking;
        sprite_index = sprSkeletonWalk;
        image_index = 0;
        alarm[0] = 300;
        
        //Set direction to walk
        image_xscale = choose(1, -1);
        speed = moveSpeed;
        if(image_xscale == 1)
            direction = 180;
        else
            direction = 0;
    }
    if(place_meeting(x, y, objHero) && objHero.myState != PlayerState.Attacking) {
        objHero.hit = true;
        objHero.hitBy = id;
    }
break;
#endregion
#region Walking
case EnemyState.Walking:
    //Check for walls
    if(place_meeting(x + image_xscale, y, objBlock)) {
        direction += 180;
        image_xscale *= -1;
    }
    //Check for Ledges
    if(!place_meeting(x + (image_xscale * abs((sprite_width / 1.25))), y + 1, objBlock)) {
        direction += 180;
        image_xscale *= -1;
    }  
    //Change to Idle State
    if(alarm[0] == -1) {
        myState = EnemyState.Idle;
        sprite_index = sprSkeletonIdle;
        image_index = 0;
        alarm[0] = 60;
        speed = 0;
    }
    //Change to charge state
    if(thePlayer != noone) {
        myState = EnemyState.Charging;
        speed = moveSpeed * 4;
        image_speed = 2.5;
    }
    //Check for damage
    if(hit) {
        EnemyTakeDamage(sprSkeletonTakeHit);
    }
    if(place_meeting(x, y, objHero) && objHero.myState != PlayerState.Attacking) {
        objHero.hit = true;
        objHero.hitBy = id;
    }
break;
#endregion
#region Charge State
case EnemyState.Charging:
    //Change to attack state
    if(distance_to_object(objHero) <= attackRange) {
        myState = EnemyState.Attacking;
        sprite_index = sprSkeletonAttack;
        image_speed = 1;
        image_index = 0;
        mask_index = sprSkeletonAttackHB;
        speed = 0;
        break;
    }
    //If we don't see player anymore, change to walking
    if(thePlayer == noone) {
        myState = EnemyState.Walking;
        image_speed = 1;
        speed = moveSpeed;
    } 
    //Check for walls
    if(place_meeting(x + image_xscale, y, objBlock)) {
        direction += 180;
        image_xscale *= -1;
    }
    //Check for Ledges
    if(!place_meeting(x + (image_xscale * abs((sprite_width / 1.25))), y + 1, objBlock)) {
        direction += 180;
        image_xscale *= -1;
    }  
    //Check for damage
    if(hit)
        EnemyTakeDamage(sprSkeletonTakeHit);
    if(place_meeting(x, y, objHero) && objHero.myState != PlayerState.Attacking) {
        objHero.hit = true;
        objHero.hitBy = id;
    }
break;
#endregion
#region Attacking
case EnemyState.Attacking:
    if(image_index > 4 && image_index < 6 && attackCounter < attackPause) {
        image_speed = 0;
        ++attackCounter;
    }
    if(attackCounter >= attackPause) {
        if(place_meeting(x, y, objHero) && objHero.myState != PlayerState.Attacking) {
            objHero.hit = true;
            objHero.hitBy = id;
        }
        image_speed = 1;
        if(!audio_is_playing(sndSkeletonSlash))
            audio_play_sound(sndSkeletonSlash, 1, false);
    }
    //Check for hit
    if(hit) {
        EnemyTakeDamage(sprSkeletonTakeHit);
        attackCounter = 0;
    }
    if(place_meeting(x, y, objHero) && objHero.myState != PlayerState.Attacking) {
        objHero.hit = true;
        objHero.hitBy = id;
    }
    //Done Attacking
    if(AnimationEnding()) {
        myState = EnemyState.Walking;
        sprite_index = sprSkeletonWalk;
        mask_index = sprSkeletonIdle;
        speed = moveSpeed;
        attackCounter = 0;
    }
break;
#endregion
#region Taking Damage
case EnemyState.TakingDamage:
    //Get Out of state
    if(AnimationEnding()) {
        if(currentHealth <= 0) { //Die
            myState = EnemyState.Dying;
            audio_play_sound(sndSkeletonDeath, 1, false);
        }
        else { //Continue Living
            myState = EnemyState.Charging;
            //Turn Around to face player
            var dir = point_direction(x, y, objHero.x, objHero.y);
            sprite_index = sprSkeletonWalk;
            if(dir > 90 && dir < 270) {
                image_xscale = -1;
                direction = 180;
            }
            else {
                image_xscale = 1;
                direction = 0;
            }
            hit = false;
            image_index = 0;
        }
    }
break;
#endregion
#region Death
case EnemyState.Dying:
    instance_destroy();
    audio_play_sound(sndSkeletonDeath, 2, false);
    var skele = instance_create_layer(x, y, "Instances", objDeadSkeleton);
    skele.image_xscale = image_xscale;
break;
#endregion
}
```

`

I tried to copy the code, watched the videos again and I tried to read through the code